# How to Move/Copy Multiple Folders to Other Multiple Folders

Tags: solaris, solaris-10

I want to move multiple folders to other multiple folders like

I have folders with name like dates  e.g 20141101 and Oct-2014

Now i want to move folders like

```
mv 201401* Jan-2014

mv 201402* Feb-2014
```

I have these folders for one whole year so want to move in one command rather then running 12 commands.

Regards

Comment: Just to clarify your question; are you asking to move all folders prefixed with `201401` into folder `Jan-2014` and much the same for `201402*`?

Comment: @bwinata Yes your understanding is fine.

Answer (score 1):

A simple command like so can be done in one line;

`mv 201401* Jan-2014; mv 201402* Feb-2014; ...`.

Alternatively, you can write a script to perform this action, but I think a single line shown above will do the trick.